# Copying multiple specific values

Tags: excel, vba

I want to search a specified column for a String value. Then I want to grab the six values to the right of that column value. I am currently doing it like this which is working correctly.

```
Set c = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="DSCR Analysis", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                  LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
```

Note here are the declarations for the following variables.

```
Property Get wsSrc() As Worksheet
     Set wsSrc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MBI DSCR")
End Property
Property Get wSrc() As Workbook
Set wSrc = ActiveWorkbook
End Property
Property Get col() As Long
    col = wsSrc.Columns.Find(What:="MBI", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).Column
End Property
Property Get col2() As Long
    col2 = wSrc.Sheets("Inputs").Columns.Find(What:="Deal Team", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False).Column
End Property

Property Get wsDest() As Worksheet
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("LBM_DSCT_DataLake.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
End Property
```

Currently I am copying a specified value from the source sheet then pasting it to the destination sheet over and over for all the different values I want to copy.
However I am wondering if it is possible to copy all the different values (ie "DSCR Analysis") to a clipboard and then paste. So the program does not "jump" back and forth between sheets rather grabs all the data it needs once, copies it, then pastes it in the destination sheet.
Below is an example of how one of my functions works wit hthe copying and pasting. I have around 20 of these where the program jumps back and forth.

```
Sub PasteCI()
 Dim c As Range, cDest As Range
    
  
    Set c = wsSrc.Columns(col).Find(What:="Commercial Income", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                  LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False)
    
    Set cDest = wsDest.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 'next paste destination. C2?
    
    If c Is Nothing Then                     'didn't make a match with Find() ?
        cDest.Resize(6, 1).Value = "-"       'fill placeholders
    Else
        c.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 6).Copy    'got match - copy range
        cDest.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
              Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you will have to rewrite some of your code to make it into a Union instead. Setup a global variable Eg: `Dim DataToCopy as Range` and you can use Union to add to it `DataToCopy = Union(Range("B2"), DataToCopy)`, after you have added all the data you want to the Union, then use `DataToCopy.Copy` and `.PasteSpecial`. A Union is almost like using Ctrl+Click to select different Cells.

Comment: Ok great, I am also worried about the case when the data to copy does not exist. Instead I want to place "-" when the data to copy DNE. can this be done also? should I do this when setting c, if so how would this be done?

Comment: that would not work into a Union, a Union only takes Ranges to keep adding to it, you can not replace an empty Range to a Text ("") on the Union. If you are still looking to copy and paste all at once you will have to do the Blank replacement to "" after the Paste.